# Why do I receive Incorrect syntax near 'PROVIDER' error when trying to create a new Azure AD server principal (logins) on Azure SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, ssms

Why do I receive Incorrect syntax near 'PROVIDER' error when trying to create a new Azure AD server principal (logins) on Azure SQL Server?

I'm following the official Microsoft documentation titled "[Create additional Azure AD server principals (logins) using SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-aad-security-tutorial#create-additional-azure-ad-server-principals-logins-using-ssms)", and I'm using SQL Server Management Studio version 18.1.

Following the documentation, I've already successfully logged into my **Azure SQL Server** using "**Active Directory - Universal with MFA support**" option, and I want to add an Active Directory user, so that my colleague can also access the same server and see the database I've created on that server. As described in the Microsoft documentation, I open a new query window, and I try to run the following SQL command:

```
USE master
GO
CREATE LOGIN [firstname.lastname@example.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
GO
```

But I immediately get the following error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 48, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'PROVIDER'.
```

Comment: Just a quick note: make sure you are actually logged into an Azure SQL DB for this. If you are accidentally logged into on-prem you'll get this error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Azure SQL Database (single database) you can only create AAD Users, not AAD Logins.  AAD Logins were added for [Azure SQL Database Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-aad-security-tutorial).

So you just [create the user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in the target database(s), eg

```
CREATE USER [someuser@somedomain.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, 

CREATE USER [someuser@somedomain.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;

Comment: Or, for an App Registration I was able to use the follow.  Be active in the database you want the user to access before running.  CREATE USER [NameOfMyAppReg] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER